# Adding Dynamic Material Design Components using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, material-design-lite

Good morning,

I am pretty new to both Material Design Lite and Knockout and I am trying to figure out steps needed to add dynamic Material Design components.  I feel like I am missing something basic here.

I am adding cards using one of their basic examples:  https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#cards-section

and am adding a contextual menu
(https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section) to the bottom right corner of the card:

I can add new cards dynamically without issue, but I cannot get the contextual menu to work on the dynamically added cards.

JSFiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/tychonomega/dyj0jLw1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <div class="mdl-card__title">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
    <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
            Get Started
        </a>
    <!-- Right aligned menu on top of button  -->
    <button id="demo-menu-top-right" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon pull-right">
      <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
    </button>

    <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-mdl-for="demo-menu-top-right">
      <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
      <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
      <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__menu">
    <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      <i class="material-icons">share</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<button data-bind="click: addNewCard">Add New Card</button>


<div id="cardContainer" data-bind="foreach: apis">
  <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <div class="mdl-card__title">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Welcome, <span data-bind="text: titleValue"></span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sagittis pellentesque lacus eleifend lacinia...
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
      <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                Get Started
            </a>
      <!-- Right aligned menu on top of button  -->
      <button data-bind="attr: {id: 'cardMoreButton_' + $index() }" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon pull-right">
        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>

      <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--top-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect" data-bind="attr: {'data-mdl-for': 'cardMoreButton_' + $index() }">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
        <li disabled class="mdl-menu__item">Disabled Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__menu">
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <i class="material-icons">share</i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function CardModel(title) {
  var self = this;

  self.titleValue = ko.observable(title);
}


var MdlViewModel = function() {

  var self = this;
  this.apis = ko.observableArray();


  self.addNewCard = function() {
    alert("Adding new APIModel!");
    self.apis.push(new CardModel("HELLO!!!"));

  }
};
ko.applyBindings(new MdlViewModel());
```

My eventual goal would be to have some options in that contextual menu, like remove, refresh from server, so on so forth.

The card above the button can be seen as an example of what I am trying to attain.

Any ideas why the context menu is not working for the dynamically generated content?  Bonus points if you can show how to bind the actions after it is working :)

By the way I did try to find the answer on my own and searched here as well.  I think that this might be one of those cases where I just don't know what I am looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44209652/392102

Comment: unfornately this did not solve it for me, I added what fixed it for me as an answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The answer was found here:  https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/855

I used

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialMenu', 'mdl-menu');
```

in my addNewCard javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CardModel(title) {
        var self = this;

        self.titleValue = ko.observable(title);
    }


    var MdlViewModel = function () {

        var self = this;
        this.apis = ko.observableArray();


        self.addNewCard = function () {
            self.apis.push(new CardModel("HELLO!!!"));
            window.componentHandler.upgradeDom('MaterialMenu', 'mdl-menu'); // added here
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new MdlViewModel());
</script>
```

and it is now working.  Interestingly enough, adding that to the fiddle does not solve the issue there, but it does in my code.